# JSON gets reversed automatically when converted to dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using the "requests" module in order to get the content of a web page which happens to be a JSON file. What I want is to convert this JSON to a Python's dictionary.

Here is the code I am using so far:

```
import requests
import json


apiURL = "http://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/"
content = requests.get(apiURL)
content = r.content
content = json.load(r)
```

While I am expecting the created dictionary to contains the whole JSON from the beggining till the end as shown in the image below:
[image]

The created dictionary starts from the middle or in another words doesn't contains the first lines of the JSON.
[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix that?

Comment: maybe try using OrderedDict instead if order matters to you: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Comment: In the JSON format the type object is considered unordered already, very similar to Python dictionaries. You can not rely on the order at any time in both languages.

Comment: What I want to do is to create a dictionary exactly like the JSON file. It's not about ordering with a specific way.